# Can you get grace period of 30 days after expiration of office 365 account my license is Office 365 Enterprise E3?

Tags: sharepoint-online, licensing

I am using Sharepoint online and have lots of data in it.So after 30 days will I get grace period if I don't want to buy license or I will have to create new account?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly this way. The demo is for testing purpose only. But you can choose if you want to have licences for 12 months (which is a little bit cheaper) or for 1 month only. In doubt call your next CSP who can tell you the right price.